# Structured Data Testing Tool fails with errors

Tags: structured-data

The following (shortened) script returns 2 errors in [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), and I don't know why. I followed the example code from [here](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1.html), but somehow it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <div xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
            xmlns:gr="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
            xmlns:review="http://purl.org/stuff/rev#"
            xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
            <div typeof="gr:Offering" about="#offeringdata">
                <div rel="foaf:page" resource=""></div>
                <div rev="gr:offers" resource="#companydata"></div>
                <div property="gr:name" content="" ></div>
                <div property="gr:description" content="" ></div>
                <div property="gr:hasStockKeepingUnit" content="" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div rel="gr:includes">
                    <div typeof="gr:SomeItems" about="#productdata">
                        <div property="gr:name" content="" ></div>
                        <div property="gr:description" content="" ></div>
                        <div rel="foaf:depiction v:image" resource=""></div>
                        <div property="gr:hasStockKeepingUnit" content="" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                        <div property="gr:category" content="" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification">
                    <div typeof="gr:UnitPriceSpecification">
                        <div property="gr:validFrom" content="2015-08-11T16:34:02Z" datatype="xsd:dateTime"></div>
                        <div property="gr:validThrough" content="2015-08-11T16:34:02Z" datatype="xsd:dateTime"></div>
                        <div property="gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement" content="C62" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                        <div property="gr:hasCurrency" content="EUR" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                        <div property="gr:hasCurrencyValue" content="95.8" datatype="xsd:float"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div property="gr:validFrom" content="2015-08-11T16:34:02Z" datatype="xsd:dateTime"></div>
                <div property="gr:validThrough" content="2015-08-11T16:34:02Z" datatype="xsd:dateTime"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="AD" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="BE" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="BG" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="DK" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="DE" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="EE" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="FI" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="FR" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="GR" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="VA" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="IE" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="IT" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="HR" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="LV" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="LI" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="LT" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="LU" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="MT" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="MC" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="NL" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="NO" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="AT" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="PL" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="PT" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="RO" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="SM" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="SE" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="CH" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="SK" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="SI" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="ES" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="CZ" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="HU" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="GB" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div property="gr:eligibleRegions" content="CY" datatype="xsd:string"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#COD"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#VISA"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#MasterCard"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ByBankTransferInAdvance"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ByInvoice"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DirectDebit"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="">
                </div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DirectDebit"></div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="">
                </div>
                <div rel="gr:acceptedPaymentMethods" resource="">
                </div>
                <div rel="gr:availableDeliveryMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeFreight"></div>
                <div rel="gr:availableDeliveryMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeFreight"></div>
                <div rel="gr:availableDeliveryMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeFreight"></div>
                <div rel="gr:availableDeliveryMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeFreight"></div>
                <div rel="gr:availableDeliveryMethods" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeFreight"></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="gr:hasPriceSpecification" resource=""></div>
                <div rel="foaf:depiction v:image" resource=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Google Structured Data Testing Tool which expects http://schema.org vocabulary while you are using Good Relations vocabulary. The GR definitions were published in 2011, while in November 2012 Good Relations vocabulary was added to Schema.org release v0.99. Announcement is http://blog.schema.org/2012/11/good-relations-and-schemaorg.html. Adopt the Schema.org vocabulary and you will have much better results with Google SDTT.